# Como hago para que estos dos campos solo funcionen al hacer click?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, funciones, eventos

[image]
Como hago para que los campos colums y rows solo funcionen al hacer click en confirm y no automaticamente, les agradeceria mucho su apoyo!

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Ya van dos preguntas que has hecho y que terminarán cerradas porque no te has leido ni el [ask] ni el [example] y las haces pensando que somos adivinos y que vemos lo que tu ves y que nos sabemos todos los códigos del mundo de memoria. Creo que cuando ya te han cerrado unas tres preguntas se cargan el usuario o algo así.  Pon tu código HTML y javascript relacionado para que podamos ayudarte, que ganas no nos faltan, pero nos lo complicas siendo tan escueto, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

creo que podrias agregar esto en tu boton

```
<a id="login">Confirm</a>
```

en el javascript le agregas esto

```
 $("a#login").click(function(){

    columns =$("#columns").val();
    rows =$("#rows").val();

});
```